# How to add front-end button to trigger pdfcrowd's node.js API to generate PDFs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, pdf, html-to-pdf

I have a MERN-stack app, and I am trying to use [pdfcrowd](https://pdfcrowd.com/doc/api/html-to-pdf/nodejs/#tips) to allow users of my app to download PDFs of the pages of my app.

In my Node APIs `index.js` file, I've added the example from the pdfcrowd docs:

```
var pdfcrowd = require("pdfcrowd");

// create the API client instance
var client = new pdfcrowd.HtmlToPdfClient("demo", "ce544b6ea52a5621fb9d55f8b542d14d");

// run the conversion and write the result to a file
client.convertUrlToFile(
    "http://www.example.com",
    "example.pdf",
    function(err, fileName) {
        if (err) return console.error("Pdfcrowd Error: " + err);
        console.log("Success: the file was created " + fileName);
    });
```

...and when I run `node index.js` from my terminal to relaunch node, the pdf file **is successfully** created. However, rather than create the pdf file on `node index.js`, I'd like to have a button on the front-end of my app (in my React code), that when clicked, generates the PDF.

I have never used `pdfcrowd` before and am new to any pdf-generation in react or node, and am not sure how to hanlde this. For example, what does the onClick handler function for the button have to look like, to be able to call the `pdfcrowd` code on the backend to generate the files.

**Edit:** I think I will use the `convertFileToFile` function rather than the `convertUrlToFile` function, as I'd like to use local routes in my app.

**Edit2:** I assume `convertFileToFile` uses the local node routes, and not my react routes. So I am not sure how to expand this code's functionality to create PDF pages from a variety of my app's pages.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Place a button in your html which will call your node backend function and on getting response back in front-end try :

```
var fileName="MyPdfFile.pdf";
var blob = new Blob([responseData], 'application/pdf');
const tempLink = document.createElement('a');
tempLink.style.display = 'none';
tempLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
tempLink.setAttribute('download', fileName);
tempLink.click();
```

Be careful of the response data type and use correct format when using Blob. You can also use library like 'blob-util' which provide many default functions for data conversion. I have used it to convert my data from base64 String to blob.